# constants k and m for a function is continuous in entire real number line

Tags: calculus

Find the constants $k$ and $m$ in the function below such that the function $f(x)$ is continuous in the entire real numberline

$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
2 & \text{ if }x<_3\\
kx+m & \text{ if }3<x<5\\
15 & \text{ if }5<x
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. And please type your questions using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Hint: Calculate $$\lim_{x\to 3^-}f(x)$$ and $$\lim_{x\to 3^+}f(x)$$. What does continuity impose on them?